# Linking external libraries CGAL and GMP

Tags: ros, target-link-libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use two external libraries:

- CGAL (Computational Geometry Algorithms Library, http://www.cgal.org/)
- GMP (GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library, http://gmplib.org/)

In my qt project, I added

```
LIBS += -lCGAL -lgmp
```

to my .pro file and it works well.

When I try to use it in my ros project, I tried

```
find_library(CGAL_LIBRARY CGAL /usr/local)
find_library(GMP_LIBRARY gmp /usr/lib)

target_link_libraries(ros_project ${CGAL_LIBRARY} ${GMP_LIBRARY} )
```

Its seems that the CGAL library is linked correctly, but the GMP library is not.
I get the following error for example:

```
error: undefined reference to `__gmpq_init'
```

Taking a look at the "CMakeCache.txt" in the ros project folder shows:

```
########################
# EXTERNAL cache entries
########################

//Path to a library.
CGAL_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/lib/libCGAL.so

//Path to a library.
GMP_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so
```

The command `sudo dpkg -L libgmp-dev` shows:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.a
/usr/include
/usr/include/gmp.h
/usr/include/gmpxx.h
/usr/include/gmp-x86_64.h
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libgmp-dev
/usr/share/doc/libgmp-dev/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libgmp-dev/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libgmp-dev/README
/usr/share/doc/libgmp-dev/copyright
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.so
/usr/share/doc/libgmp-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
```

so I guess the path is found correctly and I have absolutely no idea why I get the undefined reference. I'am using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Hendrik

**Edit:**

grep --color -Ri "gmp" ./build:

./build/CMakeCache.txt:GMP_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so

./build/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/build.make:../bin/basic_shapes: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so

./build/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/link.txt:/usr/bin/c++ -O2 -g -pthread CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/src/basic_shapes.o CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/media/truecrypt1/coding/Cpp/MastersThesis/logplan2013_code/trackGenerator/trackGenerator/src/trackGenerator.o -o ../bin/basic_shapes -rdynamic -L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib -L/usr/local/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/media/truecrypt1/coding/Cpp/MastersThesis/logplan2013_code/trackGenerator/build_lib -L/media/truecrypt1/coding/Cpp/MastersThesis/logplan2013_code/getVoronoi/build_lib -lroscpp -lrostime -lrosconsole -lroscpp_serialization -lxmlrpcpp /usr/local/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.a /usr/local/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a /usr/local/lib/libCGAL.so -lgmp /media/truecrypt1/coding/Cpp/MastersThesis/logplan2013_code/trackGenerator/build_lib/libtrackGenerator.a /media/truecrypt1/coding/Cpp/MastersThesis/logplan2013_code/getVoronoi/build_lib/libgetVoronoi.a -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib:/usr/local/lib

Binary file ./build/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/media/truecrypt1/coding/Cpp/MastersThesis/logplan2013_code/trackGenerator/trackGenerator/src/trackGenerator.o matches

Binary file ./build/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/media/truecrypt1/coding/Cpp/MastersThesis/logplan2013_code/voronoi/src/AlphaShape.o matches

Binary file ./build/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/media/truecrypt1/coding/Cpp/MastersThesis/logplan2013_code/voronoi/src/DPLineSimplification.o matches

Binary file ./build/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/media/truecrypt1/coding/Cpp/MastersThesis/logplan2013_code/voronoi/src/PolygonEnvironment.o matches

Binary file ./build/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/media/truecrypt1/coding/Cpp/MastersThesis/logplan2013_code/voronoi/src/VoronoiDiagram.o matches

Binary file ./build/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/src/basic_shapes.o matches

Occurrence of gmp is marked bold. Before the third and last occurrence of gmp, the path to the working library libCGAL.so is given, but for gmp only -lgmp, is this part of the problem?

Mani you said: "Please check all occurrences in Makefiles to make sure the build system is doing its job correctly". Where has gmp to occur when the build System has done the job correctly?

**Edit2:**

Using `find_package(GMP REQUIRED)` in CMakeLists.txt results in following:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:55 (find_package):
  Could not find module FindGMP.cmake or a configuration file for package
  GMP.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindGMP.cmake or set GMP_DIR to the
  directory containing a CMake configuration file for GMP.  The file will
  have one of the following names:

    GMPConfig.cmake
    gmp-config.cmake


[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Building package sendPgmMarker
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

I couldn't find a file named `GMPConfig.cmake` or `gmp-config.cmake`.
I used the ubuntu repositories to install gmp.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46326/linking-external-libraries-cgal-and-gmp/) by [henge266](https://answers.ros.org/users/3352/henge266/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2012-10-19**:
One more step to debug is to run `grep --color -Ri "gmp" ./build` in your package folder. Please check all occurrences in Makefiles to make sure the build system is doing its job correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you need to use `find_package` instead of `find_library` in your `CMakeList.txt`:

[Link](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Using_external_libraries)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6980807/1215297

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-14**:
You may have to use pkg-config as well.  There's a FindPkgConfig module.